# Difference between IServiceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService() (.NET Core) and ILifetimeScope.ResolveOptional() (Autofac)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, autofac

I've seen code example which retrieves a service from a context via Autofac this way:

```
services.AddSingleton<ITest, Test>(sp =>
{
            var iLifetimeScope = sp.GetRequiredService<ILifetimeScope>();
            using (var scope = iLifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope("AUTOFAC_SCOPE_NAME"))
            {
                var handler = scope.ResolveOptional(test.HandlerType) as ITestHandler;
            }
});
```

I was wondering if there is any difference by doing it this way with the .NET Core DependencyInjection tools?

```
services.AddSingleton<ITest, Test>(sp =>
{
            using (var scope = sp.CreateScope())
            {
                var handler = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService(test.HandlerType) as ITestHandler;
            }
});
```

Are those two ways equivalent?

Comment: Technically they are similar, but why would you want to do it that way?

Comment: Thanks. I’ll try to be independent from third party frameworks if the .Net Core Tools already provide a decent way of doing something.

Comment: I would question the suitability of the second code block too.. I'm not really sure what it is that you're trying to do? - With limited code, it looks wrong

Comment: Danger, Will Robinson - in either case when you dispose the scope you dispose any resolved IDisposable associated with the handler. This is bad news waiting to happen.